# Problem to run nodejs app on Gitlab Pages

Tags: node.js, github-pages, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to run my nodejs app on gitlab pages. I use a gitlab-ci.yml file for this where I deploy and run the nodejs app. Unfortunately the pipeline kills the process after 1 hour because the pipeline thinks running the nodejs app is part of the build script. I have two questions:
- Can you run a nodejs app on gitlab pages?
- If so, what is the best way to start the app?

Below you find the gitlab-ci.yml file.

Thanks!

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - build

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

install_dependencies:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm install -g nodemon
    - NODE_ENV=production nodemon app.js
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
```

Comment: The Gitlab pipeline is used for continuous integration purposes, you generally runs unit tests for your program, but you don't want to use it as a production environment.

Answer (score 4):

> Can you run a nodejs app on gitlab pages?
>   No! Gitlab pages allow you to host only static websites: https://about.gitlab.com/product/pages/
>
> If so, what is the best way to start the app?
>   If your app is static, try to use a static site generator! If you wanna play with nodejs, try other hosting platforms like [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/nodejs) or [clever cloud](https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/nodejs/nodejs/)